# Determine namespace of a function's caller

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to accurately determine the namespace of a function's caller. Looks like `*ns*` is determined by the namespace at top of the call stack.

```
user=> (ns util)
nil
util=> (defn where-am-i? [] (str *ns*))
#'util/where-am-i?
util=> (ns foo (:require [util]))
nil
foo=> (util/where-am-i?)
"foo"
foo=> (ns bar)
nil
bar=> (defn ask [] (util/where-am-i?))
#'bar/ask
bar=> (ask)
"bar"
bar=> (ns foo)
nil
foo=> (util/where-am-i?)
"foo"
foo=> (bar/ask)
"foo"
foo=>
```

Is there some other meta data I can rely on or do I need to specify this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. In the repl, `*ns*` is always set to the namespace in which the repl is; at runtime it is usually clojure.core, unless someone goes to the trouble to set it, which is uncommon.

Comment: Your second assertion doesn't seem right. I've observed `*ns*` being set to current namespace if I check it immediately after `(ns ..)`. Also see http://clojure.org/namespaces "The current namespace, *ns* can and should be set only with a call to in-ns or the ns macro, both of which create the namespace if it doesn't exist.". Regardless, I think you're right—it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: All those are happening at compile time, which as I said shows the namespace the repl is in. Try writing a function which checks `*ns*`, and calling it from some non-repl source, such as handling a web request, or from the `-main` in a compiled jar. At runtime, the repl niceties which set `*ns*` do not happen.

Comment: I suppose it happened at compile time, but it wasn't in the repl. It was in a `lein run`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your complete use case is, but judging from your example you want #'bar/ask to return its own namespace instead of returning a function that resolves the current namespace. You could simply use def instead of defn. Here is an example following on from what you did:

```
util=> (in-ns 'bar)
#<Namespace bar>
bar=> (def tell (util/where-am-i?))
#'bar/tell
bar=> (in-ns 'foo)
#<Namespace foo>
foo=> (refer 'bar :only '[tell])
nil
foo=> tell
"bar"
```

Hope this helps!