# Is there any way to have truly private functions in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

As talked about [here](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2011/04/30/not-so-private-clojure-functions), private clojure functions are not really private, just hidden. I don't like this. In java, functions marked private *cannot* be called outside the class without throwing a compile error. Is there any way to make sure that methods I declare as private really *are* private in that no one else can call them? Is there any way to at least simulate this?

Comment: I would think that you would just have a check for the namespace of the caller and fail if the namespace is not the one in which the function resides, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917633/determine-namespace-of-a-functions-caller seems to throw a wrench in that method.

Comment: " In java, functions marked private cannot be called outside the class; an error is thrown." this is not strictly true - referring to it directly gives a compilation error, but it can be accessed at runtime via reflection

Comment: Furthermore, needing to refer to the var explicitly is a similar action to runtime reflection (when referring to a var directly, you are telling the runtime to lookup the var's name in the ns, with reflection you tell the runtime to lookup the method's name in the object), and it could be argued that the current behavior is already equivalent to the java behavior, only more syntactically concise.

Comment: You need private functions so that you can control state mutation. Clojure is all about immutability and hence there is no inbuilt way in  the language for private functions.

Comment: Or you just don't want people using methods that you could change at any time, preferring instead only to expose those methods which may form a stable API for the future. This is loose coupling and it is good design. This is why many purely functional languages provide this "don't touch this" abstraction feature, such as racket's `provide` syntax. http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-provide.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to keep our terminology straight here, Java 8 has `java.util.function.Function`, but I think you actually mean java *methods*. Clojure functions (classes implementing the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface), are not methods, they are classes. `IFn` extends the `Runnable` and `Callable` interfaces.

Strictly speaking, you can actually hide a Clojure function quite deeply by implementing lexical closure so that there is no accessible Object which exposes it.

For example:

```
(ns my.hidden)

(fn not-here
   [x]
   (println "this can never be called"))
```

No code can ever call this function. This function is so hidden, that the garbage collector will likely remove it from the vm as soon as it is done creating it. Of course this isn't at all useful.

A more realistic example (but still something you probably shouldn't do):

```
(ns my.discreet)

(letfn [(a [x] (println "a with" x))
        (b [x] (println "b with" x))]
   (defn foo [x]
      (if (> (rand) 0.5)
             (a x)
            (b x))))
```

Here, the caller has no convenient way to access a or b directly. It would be possible via reflection, but only by exploiting known implementation details of your Clojure version. There is no API, so any solution would be implementation dependent. To quote one Clojure developer: "that's abusing implementation details on a level that I wouldn't feel comfortable sleeping if I did it".

But the important thing here is that hiding the functions isn't actually the idiomatic right way to do Clojure. In Clojure, when we want to code defensively, we prefer to count on immutable datatypes which ensure that ignorant or malicious coders cannot cause invalid state because we are not relying on mutation of state to implement our algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is simply that JVM way to make a private element of an object is just to put it the attribute private. Even in Java you can easily call a private function from outside, that only the compiler that hinder you to do it directly. Indirectly you can just get the class' function and call it.

In Clojure the calls are made on dynamic types objects and privacy is part of the typing.
Idiomatically privacy is only useful for namespace object hiding, and it is well managed by the compiler. Internal state private variable has no real meaning as the goal is to minimize them or better to suppress them.

Another thing, the private attribute is stored in the symbol as metadata. But we deal with values, and here there's no more metadata...

But it's probable that you're still too much in a OO point of view ;)